# Is a Playstation | Playstation-3 tag fork needed?

Tags: discussion, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tag Synonym Request: [PS1] -> [Playstation-1] ; [PS2] -> [Playstation-2] ; [PS3] -> [Playstation-3]](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2442/tag-synonym-request-ps1-playstation-1-ps2-playstation-2-ps3)

I just got done editing [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24183/how-do-i-access-content-from-the-cerberus-network-dlc) from a generic "Playstation" tag to the correct "Playstation-3" platform tag. It did, however, make me curious as to whether the playstation tag itself was being conformed to in a sensible manner.

Results were mixed. You have questions like [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22812/what-happens-to-online-saves-after-playstation-plus-expiration) which tags both Playstation and ps3, even though Playstation Plus is a feature exclusive to PS3s (I thought?), it is tagged with Playstation.

Personally, I don't think there needs to be a "Playstation" tag, nor a "Nintendo" tag for that matter. Because of the way consoles and the game industry *work*, it can reasonably be assured that each parent company will support only its latest generations, so that having a tag for the "playstation *brand*" is little better than simply having a tag of "sony".

I propose that we kill any ambiguity and rename the playstation tag to a playstation-1 tag, and remove the tag entirely from [questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21775/what-technology-does-the-playstation-network-run-on) [like](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14665/how-to-use-ps3-with-a-monitor) [these](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11539/playstation-3-hdd-change-cannot-start-the-correct-hard-disk-was-not-found) which have the tag *in addition to* a playstation-3 tag.

Answer (score 1):

PlayStation is the name of a console.  Said console had two successors, PlayStation 2 and PlayStation 3.

Now, it's incorrect to tag PS3 games with the [playstation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playstation) tag, but that doesn't mean the tag shouldn't exist.

Comment: And is there a reason to not *Extra* clarify that playstation refers specifically to the *first* playstation, and not all platforms that share its name?

Comment: @Raven namely because *nobody* calls the first console "Playstation 1". It's either "PlayStation", "PSOne", or "PSX" (see also [my answer on the ancillary question](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2442/tag-synonym-request-ps1-playstation-1-ps2-playstation-2-ps3/2444#2444))

Comment: @Mark - your ancillary question has made me realize that perhaps it should be a PSX tag, and the "playstation" tag be avoided in its entirety (except as a synonym).

Answer (score 0):

I think the tags should be [playstation-1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playstation-1), [playstation-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playstation-2), [playstation-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playstation-3), [playstation-portable](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playstation-portable) and [playstation-vita](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playstation-vita).

The [playstation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playstation) tag should be blocked as it is too generic.

Comment: As I commented on Powerlord's answer, "playstation-1" isn't a real thing: nobody calls it the "PlayStation 1".