# Tag Synonym Request: [PS1] -> [Playstation-1] ; [PS2] -> [Playstation-2] ; [PS3] -> [Playstation-3]

Tags: support, retag-request, tag-synonyms

In doing research for [this question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2441/is-a-playstation-playstation-3-tag-fork-needed), I found out that the Playstation console tags have a bit too much redundancy in the curent tagging system, with their abbreviated forms not being attributed to the full name of the consoles. (Or vice versa. I'm not sure which should be the prime tags)

Comment: Note: PlayStation One (not 1) is a specific model of the PlayStation game console.

Answer (score 6):

To expand a little on Powerlord's comment, the original PlayStation was called [PlayStation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation_%28console%29) with "PS" or "PSX" being the shortened form: not PlayStation 1, PlayStation One, or PS1 (Wikipedia claims PS1 is an alternate form, but it's unsourced).

[PSOne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSone#PSone) was the slimmer, value version of the PlayStation released when the PlayStation 2 came out.

So, if we're going to resolve this once and for all, I propose:

- [psx](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psx), [ps1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ps1), [playstation-one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playstation-one), [psone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psone), [playstation-1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playstation-1) → [playstation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playstation)
- [ps2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ps2) → [playstation-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playstation-2)
- [ps3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ps3) → [playstation-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playstation-3)
- [psp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psp) → [playstation-portable](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playstation-portable)

We'll probably have to revisit this one more time when the [PlayStation Vita](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation_Vita) starts being tossed around more colloquially. Likely:

- [psv](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psv), [psp2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psp2), [ps-vita](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ps-vita), [psvita](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psvita) → [playstation-vita](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playstation-vita)

Comment: Actually, given that ps3 and ps2 are the more populous of their tags, I think it should be inverted from what I originally suggested, so that they boil down to psx, ps2, or ps3. That way, people will hopefully stop tagging PS3 specific questions with "playstation" if they see it's a synonym for "psx".

Comment: @Raven I see the argument for both directions, but I really have no preference, as long as `psx` is favored over all others if the abbreviated form is the master tag.

Comment: I greatly favor @MarkTrapp's approach here, I want to avoid using abbreviations in console names unless at all possible.

Comment: Oh yeah, how about [tag:psp-go] → [tag:playstation-portable].

Comment: Even more confusing: [PSX is also an actual, separate device related to the PS2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSX_%28DVR%29) that was released in Japan. Good thing it's pretty unheard of outside Japan, so the rest of us can use the abbreviation safely to refer to the original PlayStation console...

Answer (score 5):

I think it should be the other way:

- [ps3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ps3) → [playstation-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playstation-3)
- [ps2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ps2) → [playstation-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playstation-2)

…and so on. I think we should do our best to avoid abbreviations in console names unless that is the only option.

Comment: from a Google indexing point of view the abbreviation have more searches done

Comment: @Blem Google usually expands acronyms.  If you search "PS3" you'll see results for "Playstation 3"

Answer (score 3):

I think the abbreviated forms are very well-known among gamers, plus SE in general favors short tags when the abbreviation is popular, so I'd like to invert Mark's suggestion:

- [psx](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psx), [playstation-one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playstation-one), [psone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psone), [playstation-1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playstation-1) → [ps1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ps1)
- [playstation-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playstation-2) → [ps2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ps2)
- [playstation-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playstation-3) → [ps3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ps3)
- [playstation-portable](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playstation-portable) → [psp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psp)

Notice that I've removed [playstation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playstation) from the list altogether - that's because that although the actual name of the first console of the series was "playstation", I think that new users posting questions might think "well, it's about my playstation, let's tag it with [playstation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playstation)", even though it's actually a ps3 that they own. Removing this tag altogether means that when a user starts writing "plays..." 3 major options will appear - [playstation-1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playstation-1), [playstation-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playstation-2) and [playstation-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playstation-3), so it's very clear which one should be used.

Comment: I'd suggest [psx] as the parent tag for the first class, over [ps1].

Comment: @Grace I always thought psx represents the whole series...

Comment: Nope, PSX is an accepted abbreviation for the first system.

Comment: I'll accept this answer when/if it gets implemented by the mods.

Comment: I think `psone` could stand to be separate, and I agree with Grace about `psx`, but otherwise this sounds good. @RavenDreamer YTMND!

Comment: @RavenDreamer - I believe this has been implemented by the mods